# Will casting a variable as an object cause that variable to lose data?

Tags: c#, object, casting

Say I have the following code

```
...
PointPair newPoint = new PointPair(123, 432);
newData((Object) newPoint);
...

public override void newData(Object data)
{
    PointPair newData;
    if (data is PointPair)
        newData = (PointPair)data;
    else
        newData = new PointPair(0, 0);

    // Do stuff with newData
}
```

Will my `PointPair` object lose data/information during the cast/uncast to/from `object`?

Does it matter if I use `object` or `Object`? (capital O)

Comment: No, casting itself does not lose any data. If you **assign** another value to a variable, the old value formerly stored in that variable is lost (aka, overwritten with the new value).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will my PointPair object lose data/information during the cast/uncast to/from object?

No, it won't.Because casting, doesn't change your object at all.It changes how is your object considered, for example when you cast it to `object`,even though the underlying type is still `PointPair` you can't access the members of `PointPair` because your `newPoint` will be treated as `object`.

> Does it matter if I use object or Object?

No, because `object` is just an alias for `Object` class.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both your questions is No. You don't lose the value of the data when casting. object is alias for Object ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c%28v=VS.100%29.aspx))

Good Luck!

Comment: Ahhh, that's the word I wanted. "Boxing".

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no data loss as such. But when you cast a reference type to an object, there is a performance hit. The compiler has to emit a **castClass** opcode to convert the reference type to the needed type, an additional instruction to process.

Answer (score 0):

> Will my `PointPair` object lose data/information during the cast/uncast
>   to/from object?

No.  Because `PointPair` is a reference type (as all C# classes are), a `PointPair` variable holds a reference to an object whose actual storage is on the managed heap.  The space required to store the *reference* is independent of the object's class, and casting is simply telling the compiler what type of object you believe your reference is pointing to.  Casting to `object` (which is actually unnecessary in your example code) says, "treat `newPoint` as though I only know it's an `object`."  The cast in `newData = (PointPair)data;` (which *is* necessary) tells the compiler, "let me treat `data` as the `PointPair` it really is."

This behavior is in contrast to, for instance, casting a `long` to an `int`.  Value types (like numerical primitive types and C# structs) are stored by value, and they take varying amounts of space.  So casting a `long` to an `int` means potential data loss, as a 64-bit value is converted to a 32-bit value.

> Does it matter if I use object or Object? (capital O)

No.  As others have said, the `object` keyword is just an alias for `Object`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Though, I do need to do this. `newData` is an overriden method in which the sub-classes accept various data types.  So they inherit `newData(object data)` which they then interpret `object data` how they see fit.